# Node.js - load .env file from a different location

Tags: node.js

I have a Node.js application which runs fine with the standard `node index.js` syntax (relative path...)
Then I had the need to run it with the absolute path in `node /home/bots/mybot/index.js` and it was working great as well.

Now I have the need to add a `.env` file which is still running great from relative path, but I'm not able to run it from absolute path anymore since it's not reading the `.env` file! I think it is looking for it in the `/` path which is not ideal of course.

EDIT: I'm currently using discord.js library which probably is using dotenv or something very similar inside.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using dotenv?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking an assumption in my mind, i.e. you're using dotenv package for the .env

From the Docs (You can specify the custom path to .env)

You may specify a custom path if your file containing environment variables is located elsewhere.

```js
require('dotenv').config({ path: '/full/custom/path/to/your/env/vars' })
```

Or you may do it using the command line, when calling your `index.js`

While running node your/absolute/path/index.js

```
node -r dotenv/config your/absolute/path/index.js dotenv_config_path=/custom/path/to/your/env/vars
```

Comment: -r with preload your dotenv so no need to load again in your package.

Comment: ii'm using discord.js library wich i'm sure use dotenv inside or something very similar because the syntax is the same. Is that "node -r dotenv/config your/absolute/path/index.js dotenv_config_path=/custom/path/to/your/env/vars" standard or i should change the code as well to make it happen?

Comment: @Alex75, if the dotenv is not yours, and you going to use that `node -r` option , you don't need change the code. :)

Comment: magic man!! tnx a lot :) just tryed and it works like a charm!

Comment: Awesome, Glad I could help @Alex75